# Pandas timedelta calculations for common sense late/early differences

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

My dataframe has two timestamp columns and I need to add a third time difference column. **How do I get *common sense* time difference between an expected time and the actual time?**

If your expected time is `0800` and you're **early** at `0730`, then you get common sense output:

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022 08:00')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022 07:30')
pd.Timedelta(t1-t2)
> Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00')

pd.Timedelta(t1-t2).seconds / 60.0  # Minutes
> 30.0
```

If your expected time is `0800` and you're **late** at `0830`, then you get rather strange output:

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022 08:00')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022 08:30')
pd.Timedelta(t1-t2)
> Timedelta('-1 days +23:30:00')

pd.Timedelta(t1-t2).seconds / 60.0  # Minutes
> 1410.0
```

Now, I see you can arrive at a more *common sense* result by subtracting 24h or `1440` minutes:

```
(pd.Timedelta(t1-t2).seconds / 60.0) - 1440 # Minutes
> -30.0
```

And I guess I can create a function and `apply()`, but seems like this should be a common need, though I don't see anything I can use in the documentation for [pandas.Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas-timedelta)

Comment: Well, the short answer is to check which one is greater, and reverse the subtraction.

Comment: I realized this as I was writing that I could write a helper function for the two cases, but, you know, Pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html), not `seconds`:

```
pd.Timedelta(t1-t2).total_seconds()/60
```

Output: `-30`